# Disable NTLM/Negotiate sign in options in aspnet5-rc1

Tags: asp.net-core

Since RC1 has released, two new sign-in/authentication methods have appeared as part of the social sign in options: `NTLM` and `Negotiate`.

They're appearing as part of the `SignInManager.GetExternalAuthenticationSchemes()` collection.

Is there a recommended method to either disable them globally, or filter them out from the collection, without hard-coding their names?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

https://github.com/aspnet/IISIntegration/issues/25

`app.UseIISPlatformHandler(options =>
{
    options.AuthenticationDescriptions.Clear();
});`

Comment: Thanks, was digging around the Identity and main repos for issues, didn't think to associate it with IIS.